# Query Excel sheet using dynamic SQL. Avoid SQL injection

Tags: sql, excel, sql-injection, dynamic-sql, openrowset

I have the following code

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(max), @SourceFile nvarchar(500);

set @SourceFile = N'\\XXXX\C$\Spreadsheet.xls';
SELECT  @SQL = N'SELECT * FROM  OPENROWSET (''Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'', ''Excel 8.0;Database='+@SourceFile+''', ''SELECT * FROM [Filer_IDs$]'' )
                WHERE   [Column1] = ''TRUE'' OR [Column2] = ''TRUE'''
EXEC (@SQL)
--------------------------    

set @SourceFile = N'\\XXXX\C$\Spread''sheet.xls';
SELECT  @SQL = N'SELECT * FROM  OPENROWSET (''Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'', ''Excel 8.0;Database=@SourceFile'', ''SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]'' )
                WHERE   [Column1] = ''TRUE'' OR [Column2] = ''TRUE'''               

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@SourceFile nvarchar(500)', @SourceFile
```

The first snippet works fine but if the spread sheet has some escape character like " `'` " in the name it fails (SQL injection). I want to use `sp_executesql` but I am getting the following error:

*OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)" returned message "The Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object 'Sheet1$'. Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly. If 'Sheet1$' is not a local object, check your network connection or contact the server administrator.".
Msg 7350, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Cannot get the column information from OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)".*

Please help.

Comment: SQL Injection aside, how are you insuring that the users of this are not using your SQL Servers permissions to load an Excel file that they should not be able to access, like Corporate Payroll?

Comment: Source files are passed from the application. All i gave here was a sample code. Keeping the access aside. i wanted to query the spreadsheet which i have access to on the network path. If the Spreadsheet has an escape character how should i run this?

Comment: Does vba allow you to use query parmaters?